# how to get background image in android (java)

Tags: java, android, image, background

I want to get background image of Home screen programmatically in Android and set it to background in my activity in my App.
How can i get background image? please guide me.

Comment: So you want to pretend you're the home screen?  Yeah, that doesn't sound malicious at all.  Luckily there's no real way to do this-  the home screen is an app, the background image in it isn't a global setting.

Comment: By background image of home screen you mean current wallpaper of the device?

Comment: well, there is [WallpaperManager#getDrawable() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#getDrawable())...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

use the drawable the way you want